# How do you create a TINYINT column with Knex?

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js

In the [knex documentation](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-integer), I only see the option to create an integer or biginteger.

For example, say I have a `movies` table with a `rating` column to store a movie's 5 star rating:

```js
// Migration script

exports.up = knex => {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable('movies', table => {
      table.uuid('id').primary()
      ...
      table.integer('rating') // <-- I want this to be a TINYINT
    })
}
```

Is there a way to do this without resorting to a raw SQL query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although the answer of @Jumshud is a good alternative way to do it, here is the short answer:

```
table.tinyint('rating');
```

I dived into Knex 0.21.6 code and found a list of methods available that are not even documented in their website. In TableBuilder file `knex/lib/schema/tablebuilder.js` the is a list of methods injected into the Prototype of a PseudoClassical pattern `TableBuilder`. The methods are created for each `columnTypes` values:

```
// For each of the column methods, create a new "ColumnBuilder" interface,
// push it onto the "allStatements" stack, and then return the interface,
// with which we can add indexes, etc.
each(columnTypes, function (type) {
  TableBuilder.prototype[type] = function () {
    const args = toArray(arguments);
    const builder = this.client.columnBuilder(this, type, args);
    this._statements.push({
      grouping: 'columns',
      builder,
    });
    return builder;
  };
});
```

And the values of the `columnTypes` array are:

```
// Each of the column types that we can add, we create a new ColumnBuilder
// instance and push it onto the statements array.
const columnTypes = [
  // Numeric
  'tinyint',
  'smallint',
  'mediumint',
  'int',
  'bigint',
  'decimal',
  'float',
  'double',
  'real',
  'bit',
  'boolean',
  'serial',

  // Date / Time
  'date',
  'datetime',
  'timestamp',
  'time',
  'year',

  // String
  'char',
  'varchar',
  'tinytext',
  'tinyText',
  'text',
  'mediumtext',
  'mediumText',
  'longtext',
  'longText',
  'binary',
  'varbinary',
  'tinyblob',
  'tinyBlob',
  'mediumblob',
  'mediumBlob',
  'blob',
  'longblob',
  'longBlob',
  'enum',
  'set',

  // Increments, Aliases, and Additional
  'bool',
  'dateTime',
  'increments',
  'bigincrements',
  'bigIncrements',
  'integer',
  'biginteger',
  'bigInteger',
  'string',
  'json',
  'jsonb',
  'uuid',
  'enu',
  'specificType',
];
```

Each value in this array is turned into a method in schema table builder.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't in the docs, thanks for finding this and putting it here!

Comment: Yeah, it would be easy to simply list them in the docs. I needed this too, and I got some free time to make a deep look at it. U're welcome

Comment: `table.tinyint()` doesn't work with TypeScript (not typed). Perhaps there's a reason it's not documented as it's internal and implementation specific?

Comment: @ElanRuusamäe, oh ok! I didn't looked at columnBuilder method and consider TypeScript when I read the source code, it might be an incomplete code considering TypeScript. But I don't think it's internal since I don't really see an automated method making use of it. The only method from other answer is `table.specificType('rating', 'tinyint(1)')`, and it's not automated. If I'm building an API generator, I can't just use a field type `tinyint` to in the automation process with `specificType` method, too much cases to handle.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `specificType` as below:

```
table.specificType('rating', 'tinyint(1)')
```

Answer (score 3):

In case, if someone needs to use `tinyint` as boolean (`TINYINT(1)`), can use the [table.boolean()](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-boolean) method.